# Distribute text with right-to-left script evenly in 15 lines inside its container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display some text in 15 rows with full width and height regardless of which device or browser you view the page. How to achieve this using Html, CSS and JS ?

Please see screen shots

This is my screen shot which it has more than 15 rows and the last line is not full width.

[image: This my screen shot which it has more than 15 rows only and the last row is not full width]

```css
.aya {
  direction: rtl !important;
  font-family: "uthmanic","Traditional Arabic", "Montserrat","sans-serif","Times New Roman";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size:25px;
}


.ayaNumber {
  font-size: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #050;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card h-100 card-body " dir="rtl" align="justify"
    style="direction: rtl !important; background-color:#f7fce3;border-color: #f7fce3;">
    <div class="card-body">
    <!-- using 'text' class below  -->
      <p class="card-text text" align="justify" style="text-align-last: right;text-align: justify;" >
        <span  class="aya">
 مَثَلُهُمْ كَمَثَلِ ٱلَّذِى ٱسْتَوْقَدَ نَارًا فَلَمَّآ أَضَآءَتْ مَا حَوْلَهُۥ ذَهَبَ ٱللَّهُ بِنُورِهِمْ وَتَرَكَهُمْ فِى ظُلُمَٰتٍ لَّا يُبْصِرُونَ﴿17﴾صُمٌّۢ بُكْمٌ عُمْىٌ فَهُمْ لَا يَرْجِعُونَ﴿18﴾أَوْ كَصَيِّبٍ مِّنَ ٱلسَّمَآءِ فِيهِ ظُلُمَٰتٌ وَرَعْدٌ وَبَرْقٌ يَجْعَلُونَ أَصَٰبِعَهُمْ فِىٓ ءَاذَانِهِم مِّنَ ٱلصَّوَٰعِقِ حَذَرَ ٱلْمَوْتِ ۚ وَٱللَّهُ مُحِيطٌۢ بِٱلْكَٰفِرِينَ﴿19﴾يَكَادُ ٱلْبَرْقُ يَخْطَفُ أَبْصَٰرَهُمْ ۖ كُلَّمَآ أَضَآءَ لَهُم مَّشَوْا۟ فِيهِ وَإِذَآ أَظْلَمَ عَلَيْهِمْ قَامُوا۟ ۚ وَلَوْ شَآءَ ٱللَّهُ لَذَهَبَ بِسَمْعِهِمْ وَأَبْصَٰرِهِمْ ۚ إِنَّ ٱللَّهَ عَلَىٰ كُلِّ شَىْءٍ قَدِيرٌ﴿20﴾يَٰٓأَيُّهَا ٱلنَّاسُ ٱعْبُدُوا۟ رَبَّكُمُ ٱلَّذِى خَلَقَكُمْ وَٱلَّذِينَ مِن قَبْلِكُمْ لَعَلَّكُمْ تَتَّقُونَ﴿21﴾ٱلَّذِى جَعَلَ لَكُمُ ٱلْأَرْضَ فِرَٰشًا وَٱلسَّمَآءَ بِنَآءً وَأَنزَلَ مِنَ ٱلسَّمَآءِ مَآءً فَأَخْرَجَ بِهِۦ مِنَ ٱلثَّمَرَٰتِ رِزْقًا لَّكُمْ ۖ فَلَا تَجْعَلُوا۟ لِلَّهِ أَندَادًا وَأَنتُمْ تَعْلَمُونَ﴿22﴾وَإِن كُنتُمْ فِى رَيْبٍ مِّمَّا نَزَّلْنَا عَلَىٰ عَبْدِنَا فَأْتُوا۟ بِسُورَةٍ مِّن مِّثْلِهِۦ وَٱدْعُوا۟ شُهَدَآءَكُم مِّن دُونِ ٱللَّهِ إِن كُنتُمْ صَٰدِقِينَ﴿23﴾فَإِن لَّمْ تَفْعَلُوا۟ وَلَن تَفْعَلُوا۟ فَٱتَّقُوا۟ ٱلنَّارَ ٱلَّتِى وَقُودُهَا ٱلنَّاسُ وَٱلْحِجَارَةُ ۖ أُعِدَّتْ لِلْكَٰفِرِينَ﴿24﴾

        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <footer style="text-align: center;">4</footer>
  </div>
```

Below is what I want to achieve (15 rows, full width and height)

[image: Here is what I want to achieve]

Comment: Do you have any code you can share so I can try and get it working

Comment: You need enough text so that it can fit in 15 lines

Comment: I pull this text form a json file and each amount of the text assign with page number and should only be in 15 lines

Comment: What is the height, width, padding/margin of this paper?

Comment: Which font are you using?

Comment: The second text does not include even a single space. Do you remove all the spaces from the text?

Comment: @mahan Thanks mahan for good points you made,  1-not sure about the padding/margin I want my page be in 15 rows regardless the size or the device you use. 2- I use one of these two fonts "uthmanic" ,"Traditional Arabic"  3-the second screenshot it is not main it is form "Golden Quran" phone app, you right look like they remove the spaces!!!. thanks again

Comment: Do you want that all 15 lines be visible in small size devices?

Comment: @mahan Yes, and filling the whole page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a line clamp as well as vw in a font size to force it to 15 lines and also shrink the text size so it will fit in 15 lines or less. Please note though this is only good for so much text, you can't shrink the font size of an entire book to fit into 15 lines.  But hopefully its good enough for what you're looking for.

here's the jsfiddle of an example so you can play with it by stretching and shrinking the output box: https://jsfiddle.net/drm6sqfx/

```css
body {
   margin: 20px;
}

.text {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 15; /* number of lines to show */
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   font-size: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam consectetur venenatis blandit. Praesent vehicula, libero non pretium vulputate, lacus arcu facilisis lectus, sed feugiat tellus nulla eu dolor. Nulla porta bibendum lectus quis euismod. Aliquam volutpat ultricies porttitor. Cras risus nisi, accumsan vel cursus ut, sollicitudin vitae dolor. Fusce scelerisque eleifend lectus in bibendum. Suspendisse lacinia egestas felis a volutpat.
```

Comment: Thanks John, tried your code and it was almost close except it cut about two and half lines, but  I want to show all the text in the page in 15 lines  (as shown in my second screenshot ). when I try to make my font small the text will not fit the whole page :(

Comment: Alternatively, as I personally don't know how Arabic really works and reads, you can squish some text together so they kind of over lap by adding this `letter-spacing: -0.09em;` to my provided code using an negative value for the letter spacing and changing it to what works for you.

Comment: If this is a specific string of text, change the font size from 5vw to 3vw and see if it fits.

Comment: This does not work for right-to-left languages like Arabic.